# draw a line by using CGPath

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

How can I draw a line by using CGPath ?

Comment: How is it difficult to tell what was being asked here?  What other interpretation of the question can there be than that the asker wanted to know how to draw a CGPath that represents a line?

Comment: There are many ways to draw a line. Core Graphics, Quartz, OpenGL, SpriteKit, GLKit, SceneKit, GL Shaders - just to name a few. We'd have to guess the intention / preferred framework of the OP.

Comment: Isn't it safe to assume Core Graphics, since he's referencing CGPath?

Answer (score 27):

As you didn't really specify more than how to draw a line with a path, I'll just give you an example.

Drawing a diagonal line between the top left corner and the bottom right (on iOS) with a path in a UIView's drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**theView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface theView : UIView {
}

@end
```

**theView.m**

```
#import "theView.h"

@implementation theView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0,0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,20,20);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end
```

Create the files mentioned above.
Window-based app: Add new UIView and change its class to theView.
View-based app: Change the UIView class to theView.
Finally hit 'build and run' :)

Result: Red diagonal line.

Comment: shouldn't you also release the path or something?

Comment: I don't think you answered the question.  The OP wants to know how to create a CGPath that represents a line and draw that CGPath.